# Between Plotly Dash&Power BI, which one shall I learn to achieve similar result?

Tags: python, powerbi, plotly-dash

I program in Python with Pandas, and already used Plotly but only with basic level since a year,
does it take less time to learn Dash or Power BI to achieve the same result, which way is more efficient?
like the data visualization fanciness level //(divided by) time spent to learn

Comment: I think this kind of discussion would be better suited for reddit.

Answer (score 1):

We do not exactly compare same stuff.

Plotly is for making visualisation
Dash for making interface around visualisations (so you can use Dash inside Plotly)

- Plotly is for making visualisation
- Dash for making interface around visualisations (so you can use Dash inside Plotly)
- PowerBi is also for making visualition

I will say Plotly, and Power BI could do same stuff, maybe PowerBi is more user friendly because it is also oriented to non programmer but It is not free but it integrates well with Microsoft tools.

You can also have a look at [Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/fr-fr) or [Qlik](https://www.qlik.com/fr-fr/), which are Power BI competitors.

If you are into similar Dash stuff, you can have a look at [Panel](https://panel.holoviz.org/) and [Voila](https://voila-gallery.org/)